# How to show the correct order of dates in x axis in ggplot after having them as factors and not as date class

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I am trying to plot dates on x-axis and cases on y-axis. I have a date (i.e. 28/02/2020) that is missing from the data set. When I was trying to plot in ggplot it had a gap in the x-axis between the 27/02/2020 and the 29/02/2020. I researched the forum and found that I needed to turn my dates class into factors which I did and it worked great. However, right now I can't make the dates appear the way I want in the x-axis which is for example the 27/02/2020 instead of 0020/02/27 as you can see from the plot.

My code:

```
data<- structure(list(date = structure(25:1, .Label = c("0020-02-27", 
                                             "0020-02-29", "0020-03-01", "0020-03-02", "0020-03-03", "0020-03-04", 
                                             "0020-03-05", "0020-03-06", "0020-03-07", "0020-03-08", "0020-03-09", 
                                             "0020-03-10", "0020-03-11", "0020-03-12", "0020-03-13", "0020-03-14", 
                                             "0020-03-15", "0020-03-16", "0020-03-17", "0020-03-18", "0020-03-19", 
                                             "0020-03-20", "0020-03-21", "0020-03-22", "0020-03-23"), class = "factor"), 
           cases = c(69L, 71L, 104L, 36L, 91L, 92L, 57L, 48L, 23L, 128L, 
                     160L, 252L, 151L, 75L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                     1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1548L, 1549L, 
                                                                   1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 1558L, 
                                                                   1559L, 1560L, 1561L, 1562L, 1563L, 1564L, 1565L, 1566L, 1567L, 
                                                                   1568L, 1569L, 1570L, 1571L, 1573L))
library(ggplot2)

a<- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=cases)) +
geom_bar(stat= "identity") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=55, hjust=1))

a
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
data <- structure(list(
  date = structure(25:1, .Label = c(
    "0020-02-27",
    "0020-02-29", "0020-03-01", "0020-03-02", "0020-03-03", "0020-03-04",
    "0020-03-05", "0020-03-06", "0020-03-07", "0020-03-08", "0020-03-09",
    "0020-03-10", "0020-03-11", "0020-03-12", "0020-03-13", "0020-03-14",
    "0020-03-15", "0020-03-16", "0020-03-17", "0020-03-18", "0020-03-19",
    "0020-03-20", "0020-03-21", "0020-03-22", "0020-03-23"
  ), class = "factor"),
  cases = c(
    69L, 71L, 104L, 36L, 91L, 92L, 57L, 48L, 23L, 128L,
    160L, 252L, 151L, 75L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  1548L, 1549L,
  1550L, 1551L, 1552L, 1553L, 1554L, 1555L, 1556L, 1557L, 1558L,
  1559L, 1560L, 1561L, 1562L, 1563L, 1564L, 1565L, 1566L, 1567L,
  1568L, 1569L, 1570L, 1571L, 1573L
))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)

a <- data %>% 
  mutate(date1 = stringr::str_replace(date, "0020", "2020"),
         date1 = lubridate::as_date(date1),
         date2 = format(date1, "%d-%m-%Y"),
         date2 = forcats::fct_reorder(date2, date1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date2, y = cases)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 55, hjust = 1))
a
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Stefan. Yes it did :) Thank you so so much for you help! Much appreciated!